# SSAS connection with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, ssas

We are moving on Postgres from Oracle EE, Currently we have SSAS cube connecting to Oracle for doing daily cube refresh. 
Does any one know postgres driver to make is compatible source of database. Microsoft site does not mention anything about postgres database compatibility for multidimensional (MOLAP) project.

Answer (score 1):

[Multidimensional Models don't support PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/supported-data-sources-ssas-multidimensional).  Either copy the data to a SQL Server and build from there, or build a new SSAS Tabular model and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks, Currently we are using similar solution keeping Oracle SE as daily data store and moving data to SSAS Cube, but want to eliminate extra layer of Oracle and want to have all cube processing out of postgres. I have gone through the page you gave and it says MOLAP can be used with OLE DB proviers, found one - https://www.pgoledb.com/  but could not get more information on google for these drivers.

Comment: You can try, but it's not supported.  Also you can also try things like SQL Server linked server, or SSIS Partition Processing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/partition-processing-destination?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Again thanks a lot David. gone through linked server, and it looks great idea, not sure about performance hit but surely its worth to try.

Comment: Performance is the thing to worry about for linked server.  As a best-practice install a SQL Server instance on your SSAS server dedicated to hosting the linked server definitions and third-party drivers.  And restart this SQL instance occasionally, perhaps after every time you process the cube.

Comment: Thanks again David.

Comment: Struggled to get the data out using linked server, also found that it does "select * from table" and ignore where clause part, once all data fetch back to sql server it applies filter condition, this is not a solution for us because we have quite big table and complex queries on top of it. Let me know if you any other possible hacks. Thanks.

Comment: To use a linked server you would move the complex query into a view on the target database.

Comment: I got success with third party driver and so far it looks working.

Comment: We gone live with SSAS cube sourcing data with postgres as warehouse!